# STS 3.7.2 does not support virgo? Any tooling support?

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-virgo

I am using Spring Tool Suite(STS) as IDE. My current version is *sts-2.9.1*. I am trying to upgrade my java version to *java1.8*. As my current version of STS doesnot support *java1.8*, I decided to upgrade STS. For which, I have installed latest *STS-3.7.2*. It supports java1.8. it is ok. But new problem has come. For development I use Virgo server. Unfortunately STS has stopped support for Virgo by default from version 3.6.

**Now my problem is, I want to use Virgo server with latest STS(3.7.2). How do i do it?** I tried the solution below:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/Tooling

But it did not work. Anybody faced the same problem as me? Anybody have any solution? or Any tooling method i can follow? Please suggest.

**Update:**

Yeah i tried Snapchat.. but i got the following error in my IDE:

*An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.websphere.v8.core,1.0.350.v20151130_1844
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,oracle.eclipse.tools.rest.lib,8.5.1.201601071755.*

Comment: The STS 3.7.2 distribution is based on Eclipse Mars 4.5, so you need to try the Virgo tooling snapshot update site. If you tried that, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I updated my question..

Comment: That looks like a problem with other update sites that you have configured in your STS. Please go to the Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites and reload or deactivate the update sites that might belong to those features (looks like ibm websphere tooling and oracle tooling). Hope that helps!!!